# phpqrcode library - where do I put this thing on my server?

Tags: php, qr-code

I was looking at qr code generating libraries and I decided to go with phpqrcode to generate some codes on my server that I can send to mobile devices on command. My only problem is I dont know where to install the library for use. Im running windows server 2008 r2 IIS so Im guessing I should place the library with the rest of my php scripts but Im not sure and before I take on messing with it I just wanted some pointers from some one more experienced than myself in that area.

Comment: Just put it anywhere in the [`include_path`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.include-path), like any other script that you need to include...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as it is just a php library - you can put it anywhere you want in your filesystem.

The common approach for single used library is to put it a level upper than your web-root